# How to cancel an Observable interval in case of error in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service in an Angular 5 application that regularly polls an API to see how many notifications a user has:

```
public getRegularNotificationCountForUser(userid): Observable<number> {    
  return Observable.interval(5000)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get<number>(this.baseUrl + '/getNotificationCountForUser?UserId=' + userid));
}
```

I call this service from the ngInit function in my header:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.getRegularNotificationCountForUser(this.currentUser.id)
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.notificationsCount = result as number;
    });
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. If there is an error from the API, how can I stop the client from polling the service?  If I get a 500 I want to leave the server alone, and if I get a 401 I want to make sure the front end logs the user out.
2. Is this the right way of doing this?  The API can handle the expected load, but does this cause any performance issues on the client side?

I'd be very thankful for any suggestions on how to improve this code.

Comment: Have you looked into using a library like Socket.io? https://socket.io

Comment: sigh, why the downvote?

Comment: No, wasn't aware of that, will check it out @DanielWStrimpel, although typically I try to stay away from 3rd party dependencies, the requirement seems quite simple

Comment: It can provide you with a mechanism for the server to push the notifications to the client instead of the client continually polling. It was just in reference to your second question

Comment: Looks good but from initial reading it requires nodeJS as a backend server?  My API backend is .net core

Comment: You don't have to use that. `WebSocket` is supported in modern browsers. Here is a Microsoft blog about web socket creation in .net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets

Comment: Same recomendation that everybody, use WebSocket to push changes to the client, pulling every 5 seconds will overload the server and probably without a reason (maybe you don't have changes for 10 minutes)

Comment: Looking further, agree this is the way to go, but best to wait for SignalIr implementation in .NET Core 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is an error from the API, how can I stop the client from polling the service?

A HTTP error will propagate as an error notification in the observable, which `switchMap` will propagate as well. As per the observable contract, this means that the subscription is now closed; meaning to just end polling you don't have to do anything anymore (if I were you, I'd probably want the opposite – catch errors and continue. Do you really want to kill the polling because of what is likely a temporary network issue?)

> If I get a 500 I want to leave the server alone, and if I get a 401 I want to make sure the front end logs the user out.

If you want the error to propagate, but react to it anyway, then you can make use of the second argument to `subscribe`:

```js
obs$.subscribe(null, err => {
  if (err.status === 401) {
    this.userService.logOut();
  }
});
```

> The API can handle the expected load, but does this cause any performance issues on the client side?

IMHO, the main problem is that you're not waiting for responses; every 5s, you will start a new request. On slow connections, this means

- If the request takes three seconds to come back, there's only ever a 2s time window where no request is on-going.
- If the request takes 5s or longer, you will *never* get a response since `switchMap` will cancel the previous request.

You could use `mergeMap` to deal with the second issue, but it's typically still better to wait the 5s between response and request rather than between two requests.

That said, if you *can* use something like websockets, you would definitely get a better user experience out of using that. Load will be minimal as unnecessary calls are prevented and the data is pushed to the user in real-time rather than with up to 5s delay.

Comment: Using repeatWhen piped after the request instead of interval before it will fix that problem with slow/overlapping requests.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that @funkizer?

Comment: return this.http.get().repeatWhen(() => Observable.timer(5000,5000))

Comment: Or the newer, piped way: this.http.get().pipe(repeatWhen(() => timer(5000,5000)))

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error from the API, the error is dispatched threw the whole observable chain and cancel the source interval. You can react to this error (handle 500 or 401) in the subscribe (the second parameter is a callback for error).

With a switchMap, the previous call is cancelled if the response is not received by the time a new call is made, so I don't think it will to too heavy to handle for the client.